# Use object properties as arguments in reactive crud repository @Query methods

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-r2dbc

Try to solve the issue with usage filter object properties as arguments in `@Query` methods in reactive crud repository using `spring-data-r2dbc`.

```
@Query("SELECT id, someId FROM Foo WHERE someId=:query.someId"")
Flux<Foo> findByCollectionQuery(FooCollectionQuery query);
```

FooCollectionQuery:

```
@Value
public class PaymentCollectionQuery {

    @NotNull
    UUID someId;

}
```

Is there a possibility to provide the whole `PaymentCollectionQuery` object to `@Query` annotations specifying concrete property in query?

Right now I got the following exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Binding parameters is not supported for the statement 'SELECT id, someId FROM Foo WHERE someId=query.someId'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [SpEL](https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions):

```
@Query("SELECT id, someId FROM Foo WHERE someId = :#{#query.someId}")
Flux<Foo> findByCollectionQuery(@Param("query") FooCollectionQuery query);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems only Spring JPA support it, but JPA don't support R2DBC, only JDBC. Found related issue regarding SpEL usage with R2DBC - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-r2dbc/issues/164 but no progress.